# Editing a form with PHP and MySQL: Best way to obtain an ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I have a MYSQL table with edit and delete links on each row. The edit link goes to edit_patient.php which has a form (actually, a copy of the form originally used to insert patient into the database). After few tries, the script is working although I guess it could be improved (indeed, I get a notice of "Undefined index: id" when I submit the edits. The ID is passed to the edit_patient.php file through a GET procedure. Relevant code as follows:

```
// Check for a valid user ID, through GET or POST:
if ( (isset($_GET['id'])) && (is_numeric($_GET['id'])) ) { // From view_patient.php
$id = $_GET['id'];

} elseif ( (isset($_POST['id'])) && (is_numeric($_POST['id'])) ) { // Form submission.
$id = $_POST['id'];

} else { // No valid ID, kill the script.
echo '<p>Sorry, it is not possible to update patient info at this time</p>';
include ('../elements/layouts/footer.php'); 
exit();
}
```

And, after some clean up and check on submitted values:

```
if($action['result'] != 'error'){    



        // Make the query:
$q = "UPDATE `demographics` 
              SET lastname='$lastname', firstname='$firstname', clinic='$clinic',     sex='$sex', dob='$dob', age='$age', 
                  disease_1='$disease_1', disease_2='$disease_2', disease_3='$disease_3', address='$address', city='$city', country='$country', 
                  zip='$zip', phone_1='$phone_1', phone_2='$phone_2', phone_3='$phone_3',  email_1='$email_1', email_2='$email_2', 
                  physician='$physician', notes='$notes' 
              WHERE dem_id=$id   
              LIMIT 1";            

        $r = @mysqli_query ($db_connect, $q);

        if (mysqli_affected_rows($db_connect) == 1) { // If it ran OK.
                            // Tell the user we have edited patient data successfully                    
                $action['result'] = 'success';
                array_push($text,'Patient data have been updated on databank');   


    }else{

        $action['result'] = 'error';
        array_push($text,'Patient data could not be changed on databank. Reason: ' . 
                            '<p>' . mysqli_error($db_connect) . '<br /><br />Query: ' . $r . '</p>');


    } // End of if (empty($errors)) IF.
} // End of if (empty rows))
```

Ok, so far so good. Now, in order to show already inserted data, I run another query:

```
// Retrieve the user's information:
$q = "SELECT lastname, firstname, clinic, sex, dob, age, disease_1, disease_2, disease_3, address, city, country, zip, phone_1, 
         phone_2, phone_3,  email_1, email_2, physician, notes 
  FROM `demographics` 
  WHERE dem_id='".$_GET['id']."'";      
$r = @mysqli_query ($db_connect, $q);

if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) { // Valid user ID, show the form.

// Get the user's information:
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($r);

// Create the form:
```

Here, the critical row I do not understand is `WHERE dem_id='".$_GET['id']."'";` --> If I it leave as it is, the script runs almost Ok but then I get a notice of undefined index id.

However, when I replace with `WHERE dem_id=$id";` as in the first query, the script gives a fatal error of `undefined variable: id`.

Finally, to submit the form I use the following command:
    " /> that is working Ok, but it is not working when I use:
    " />

Can anyone help me to understand why, and how to correct the issue, I'd rather prefer to be able to use simply `$id` (I believe is straight forward and simple) but for some reason is not working as expected. Finally, I would like to be able to report in the form to be edited also data inserted with radio buttons and drop-down (select) menus. Any advice on that would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Thank you for the editing Agnes, really appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your specific record has been updated after the submit button in your edit_patient.php ? If it works and after next which page is display ..? Is it is Display.php (i.e. all record display page ) ? Please be specify first and i really help you to solve your query.

Comment: Hey user321, thank you for the prompt reply ! Yes I confirm the record is updated just fine in the database. This when I use the $_GET['id'] construct. On the other hand, when I use dem_id=$id (as I wish) it does not work (apparently, $id is not defined)...thanks a lot for the support !

Comment: woops almost forgot to say: when the record is updated, the user get a "so far so good" message and that's it for the moment...